# Blowing up spheres in a face centered cubic (fcc) packing geometry just enough to cover the volume of the lattice

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, sphere-packing

Imagine I have an infinite lattice of spheres packed in a face centered cubic (fcc) lattice geometry which has the basis: $((-1, -1, 0), (1, -1, 0), (0, 1, -1))$.  Here, provided that sphere-sphere intersection is forbidden, the maximum non-intersecting radius of each sphere is $r_c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Let $R_v > \frac{r_c\sqrt{18}}{\pi}$ be the minimum radius of each sphere in the fcc packing arrangment s.t., allowing for sphere-sphere overlaps, no point in the lattice is outside of a sphere.  Here, $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{18}}=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{2}}$ is the maximum possible packing density of non-intersecting spheres as per Hales' proof of the Kepler conjecture.

What is the exact value of $R_v$?  Can this value be easily calculated for other sphere packing geometries provided the lattice basis?

Update: Noam D. Elkies answered by question in the comments below.  What I'm looking for is the "covering radius" for the lattice.  I'm currently searching for this value for the fcc/$A_3$ lattice, but if anyone happens to know it, it would be great if you could help me out!

Update 2: The covering radius for the fcc/$A_3$ lattice appears to simply be $R_v=r_c*\sqrt{2}=1$.

Comment: That's called the *covering radius* of the lattice.
See Conway and Sloane's *Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups*
for more information, including the covering radius of this lattice
(which they call $A_3$) and many others.

Comment: @Noam D. Elkies Thanks so much for your response, that more or less answers my question.

Comment: A caution, SPLAG mostly write the covering radius as a multiple of the packing radius, which you have already scaled as $1/\sqrt 2.$

Answer (score 1):

Although not directly answering the question, the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63694/diameter-of-voronoi-cell-of-the-lattice-what-about-rn-what-about-small-n-2) highlights connections between the question of $R_v$ and the Voronoi cell of this lattice.  In short, it turns out that $R_v$ is the maximal distance from a lattice point to any of its Voronoi vertices.  Computing Voronoi vertices can be done relatively quickly, certainly in 3D.

If the points are not arranged on a lattice, then a "covering radius" of the set of points can be defined as the maximum/supremum over the $R_v$, where $R_v$ can be different for each point.  Of course this reduces to the above in the case of lattices, where $R_v$ is identical for all points.